# Convex hull of set of sparse vectors?

Tags: vector-spaces, convex-analysis

I am trying to understand how one can define the convex hull of sparse vectors.

I understand that for k sparse vectors can be described as a union of subspaces (such as in: http://www.ifp.illinois.edu/~minhdo/publications/SampUniS.pdf). However, the set of sparse vectors obviously does not form a subspace, nor are k-sparse vectors a convex set (since we can add two k sparse vectors and have the result not lie within the set).

Therefore, how can one have a convex hull on a non-convex set?

Comment: The convex hull of sufficiently many sparse vectors might contain non-sparse vectors. Where is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea of the convex hull is to form a convex set from the set of starting vectors. So it is okay that the vectors themselves are not convex.

One way to define the convex hull of a finite set of points is that it is the set of all points that can be written as a convex combination of your initial starting vectors. Formally, say your vectors are $\{x_1,\ldots, x_n\}$. Then the convex hull of these vectors is:

$\{y\ |\  \exists \lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n: \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i x_i=y, \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i = 1, \lambda_i\geq 0\}$

Regarding your example of adding two sparse vectors, this resulting point is actually not in the convex hull, since that would be equivalent to setting $\lambda_i=\lambda_j=1$ for the two vectors $x_i,x_j$ that you are adding.